# Use FindAll() method on List<T>

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of objects with two properties each. I'd like to sort some of them out into another list based on one of their properties by using `FindAll()`. See example code below:

```
namespace Example {

    class Tower {
         public string name { get; set; }
         public int hight { get; set; }
    }

    class Program {
          static void Main (string[] args) {
                 List<Tower> towers = new List<Tower>();

                 towers.Add(new Tower() { Name = "tower1", Hight = 25 });
                 towers.Add(new Tower() { Name = "tower2", Hight = 50 });
                 towers.Add(new Tower() { Name = "tower3", Hight = 25 });

                 List<Tower> short_towers = towers.FindAll(new Tower() { Hight = 25 });
          }
     }
}
```

But it always says:

> failed converting Example.Tower into System.Predicate<Example.Tower>'.

What am I doing wrong? Does someone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`List<T>.FindAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findall?view=net-5.0) takes a delegate as input, in particular a `Predicate<T>`.

The `Predicate<T>` delegate can be defined as follows:

```
private bool FindShortTowers(Tower t)
{
    return t.Height <= 25;
}

// then, in some other method:

Predicate<Tower> predicate = FindShortTowers;
var shortTowers = towers.FindAll(predicate);
```

It is however customary to use a lambda expression rather than to explicitly define a delegate of type `Predicate<T>`:

```
var shortTowers = towers.FindAll(t => t.Height <= 25);
```

You can also use [Enumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) from `System.Linq`:

```
var shortTowers = towers.Where(t => t.Height <= 25);
```

Comment: Thanks al lot m8!

Answer (score 5):

[`List<T>.FindAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findall?view=net-5.0) requires a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=net-5.0) as its parameter, not an instance of `T`. For example:

```
List<Tower> short_towers = towers.FindAll(t => t.Hight == 25);
```

Though perhaps, given the name of the variable, you want all towers 25 or under:

```
List<Tower> short_towers = towers.FindAll(t => t.Hight <= 25);
```

Comment: Thx a lot, that really helped me :D